# CMOCKA / Linker : 'wrap'ping lots of functions

Tags: c, unit-testing, linker, cmocka

I recently came across the '[cmocka](https://cmocka.org/)' mocking library for C. I was able to mock a single function and test the caller function successfully. Now i need it to use it for a project that i am working on, where it is required to mock a large number of functions. How to pass all the functions that I want to mock to the 'wrap' argument of Linker ? Is it possible to store the names of functions in a file, so that it could be picked up the linker ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Invoke the compiler like this:

`gcc -g -Wl,--wrap=something,--wrap=somethingElse code_new.c headers.c -l cmocka`