# gcc: error: unrecognized option --wrap

Tags: gcc, linker-errors, linker-flags

[Update] Sorry for top posting, but it might help to know this first, as it probably changes the problem.

The `--wrap` is an option to the linker `ld`, not to `gcc`.

But my Eclipse project is using `gcc` for the link stage.

How can I use wrap functions, as needed for `cmocka` unit testing?

---

I am using `gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3`.

I am trying to use the linker option `--wrap` as specified [here](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.23.1/ld/Options.html#index-g_t_002d_002dwrap_003d_0040var_007bsymbol_007d-263) in order to use [cmocka](https://cmocka.org/) to unit test C code.

The error is

```
make all 
Building target: unit_test_C_code_example_project
Invoking: GCC C Linker
gcc --wrap=add -o "unit_test_C_code_example_project"  ./test_scripts/test_maths.o  ./software_under_test/mocks/mock_add.o  ./software_under_test/maths.o   -lcmocka
gcc: error: unrecognized option ‘--wrap=add’
make: *** [unit_test_C_code_example_project] Error 1
```

So, the linker is complaining about the `--wrap=add` option, but I don't know why.

---

Inevitably, if I don't post code, someone will request it, so here it is, even though I doubt that it is of relevance to a linker option problem:

In my unit test main, I have

```
static void test_multiply_two_by_three(void **state)
{
    will_return(__wrap_add(0, 2), 2);
    will_return(__wrap_add(2, 2), 4);
    will_return(__wrap_add(4, 2), 6);

    assert_int_equal(multiply(2, 3), 6);
}
```

In another file, I declare the mock function

```
int __wrap_add(int a, int b)
{
    return mock();
}
```

and, in my Software Under Test, the function to be wrapped is called

```
int multiply(int x, int y)
{
    int total = 0;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < y; i++)
        total += add(total, x);

    return total;
}
```

Please note that there is no function called `add()` anywhere in the build. What I am trying to achieve is to mock that function, using the `__wrap_add` linker option. Why does the linker reject it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass options to the linker with `-Wl,<linker-option>`. Alternatively there's `-Xlinker <option>` for some versions of gcc. Try `gcc -Wl,--wrap=add ...`

Comment: You sir, are a genius!!  Btw, if I wanted a second, say function two, how would that look? `gcc -Wl,--wrap=add --wrap=two` or `gcc -Wl,--wrap=add -Wl,--wrap=two`?

Comment: You can pass multiple options with `-Wl,<option1>,<option2>,...`, so I'm guessing `-Wl,--wrap=add,--wrap=two`

Comment: you are correct. From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32709235/cmocka-linker-wrapping-lots-of-functions ... `gcc -g -Wl,--wrap=something,--wrap=somethingElse code_new.c headers.c -l cmocka`

Comment: A year later, and I also got it wokrking with two separate `-Wl, wrap=`, with no intervening comma. E.g. `Wl,--wrap=something --wrap=somethingElse`